# Horizontal lines do not fit the table width *UPD!*

Tags: tables

I an formatting a table at the moment and cannot figure out why the horizontal lines on the right of this table look out. You can see it better by commenting the "\renewcommands" of the preamble out.

Second point, commenting the geometry package out I get the output where the lines are shorter than the table width.

Why do my lines do not fit the line? How can I fix it? How the geometry package influence the table, if I do not use it here?

You will find the code below. Thank you!

```
\documentclass[12pt,ansinew,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[german]{babel} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\newcolumntype{m}{>{$}c<{$}}

\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{1.9ex}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!15}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{|m|m|mmmmmm|}
\specialrule{0.08em}{0em}{0em}
A & B & \text{nicht} \ A & A \ \text{und} \ B & A \ \text{oder}\ B & A   \Rightarrow B & B \Rightarrow A & A \Leftrightarrow B\\
\specialrule{0.05em}{0em}{0em}
f & f & w & f & f & w & w & w\\
f & w & w & f & w & w & f & f\\
w & f & f & f & w & f & w & f\\
w & w & f & w & w & w & w & w\\
\specialrule{0.08em}{0em}{0em}
\end{tabular*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's always a bonus for us if you strip your document down a bit so that it's minimal. There are a lot of custom commands and environments and unnecessary packages here that only serve to make your question a little bit harder to answer. If you get rid of them, it will make your question that bit more attractive and your answer will come that bit faster.

Comment: (I know it's a potential pain for you, but please try to make sure you don't remove packages from your preamble that *are* relevant, see this page for more advice: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) It's like everything, the more you put in, the more you get out

Comment: Doing what Au101 suggested is also a good thing for you, as you notice things like that you load the `array` package twice ;)

Comment: You also misspelled `\displaystyle` in `\newcolumntype{D}{>{$\displaystile}X<{$}}` which will surely bite you sooner or later

Comment: I ran your example and got [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QJtHu.png) which looks OK, the `\noindent` at the start is wrong though, as is using `[h]`

Comment: I will do it with a great pleasure in the next post! As I said in the question, my minimal example produces a different output, although I remove only unnecessary packages from the preamble list.  That is why I came to the idea, that if packages influence each other, it would be less difficult and useful for an experienced reader to have the whole list of packages to point out the problem. That is why I added the whole package list. Thank you for the link!

Comment: @Kirill Sure, I mean, the answer is often package conflicts, it's always important to have a complete preamble with all the *relevant* packages. But ideally the MWE would have none of the irrelevant ones. It's good if you do the work of eliminating unnecessary packages for us, by commenting each one out, seeing if it makes any difference, and getting rid of them if it doesn't. I know that is a pain and I can understand not bothering (after all the experienced guys will know what's relevant right)

Comment: But somewhere between all of those packages and the `\newenvironment`s and everything and not enough information to answer the question is a happy medium. That's quite a wall of code to be confronted with. Which is fine, but it's a courtesy to us to trim it down if you can, and that can only help you get the answers you want

Comment: Mr. David Carlisle, this is exactly the output that I have. If you zoom in the right side of the table, you will see that the lines are wider a bit than a right column line. That was the point.

Comment: I got it, Au101 :) Thank you for an important advice!

Comment: I fixed the code, will be glad if that helps.

Comment: oh just change `begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}` to `begin{tabular}` there is no advantage to making the table too wide, and you haven't added any stretchable space to allow it to be wide.

Comment: Mr. David Carlisle, that works wonderful here, thank you! I wanted the table to be displayed in the whole page width for the case that I change the document font to 11pt or 10pt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discrepancy in line width and table width arise because you prescribe table width, but use columns which with is adopted to width of cells content which sum si smaller than text width.

Solution: instead of `{tabular*}{\textwidth}` use `{tabularx}{\textwidth}` and use suitability modified `tabularx` column type `X`. For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,ansinew,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}

\newcolumntype{m}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering \arraybackslash}X}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering % <-- changed
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!15}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{$}C<{$}|>{$}C<{$}|*{6}{>{$}C<{$}}|}
\specialrule{0.08em}{0em}{0em}
A & B & \text{nicht} \ A & A \ \text{und} \ B & A \ \text{oder}\ B & A   \Rightarrow B & B \Rightarrow A & A \Leftrightarrow B\\
\hline%\specialrule{0.05em}{0em}{0em}
f & f & w & f & f & w & w & w\\
%\midrule
f & w & w & f & w & w & f & f\\
%\midrule
w & f & f & f & w & f & w & f\\
%\midrule
w & w & f & w & w & w & w & w\\
\hline%\specialrule{0.08em}{0em}{0em}
\end{tabularx}
\caption{Wahrheitstafel, $w$ = wahr $\land$ $f$ = falsch}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Usin `tabularx` table environment doesn't require that all columns had to be some sort of `X` type. You can use also columns type from `tabular`, however at least one had to be `X` type or based on it. For example if in above MWE you replace row with definition of columns with:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|m|m|*{6}{>{$}C<{$}}|}
```

you will obtain more nice table (to my taste, of course):

[image]

Comment: It works wonderful, thank you! Herewith:
1) Why there is {width} specificator in tabular*, if X does not work in this environment? I tried to do th whole width page in this environment but got an erroe message trying to use the X attribute there.
2) Is \centering work only in text mode, not in math mode?
3) Why did you use \centering in the middle of the code?

Thank you!

Comment: @Kirill, good question ... but `X` column tape define `tabularx` package with function that it automatically calculate column width. Such facility `tabular*` hasn't.  So with it you are on own to define column width. In some situation is handy to left to it calculation of `tabcolsep` with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`, i e. in your case `\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|m|m|mmmmmm|}` which unfortunately doesn't work well with colored rows.

Comment: True. That's why I used "specialrule(s)" for the table, also. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Kirill, see edit of my answer. use of `specialrule` hasn't any effect on column width, so I use ordinary `\hline`. And, if answer solve your problem, you can accept it ... :-)

Comment: I will definitly use it and accept it herewith! :) Or is there any function on the page that I can mark the answer as accepted?

Comment: yes,  check mark on top left side of answer. just click on it !

Comment: Oh, sorry :) I use Windows basic contrast theme with no permition to graphics, so I do not even see them. And it was my first question on the portal. But I hope that I've clicked on the right one :) thank you again.